What's the relation between "social-liberalism" and "socialism"?
What's the relation between "social-liberalism" and "socialism"?
Social liberalism seems to have emerged out of liberal circles, more than workers movements or typical (proto-)socialist circles (Meslier, Babeuf, Fourier, Cabet, Blanqui, Weitling, Engels, Marx, etc.)
It was introduced, mainly in England, by people like Jeremy Bentham, John Stuart Mill, Leonard Hobhouse, Thomas Hill Green. Again, I don't have the impression that they have any human relation/contact with the movements and people cited above.

Does this answer your question? To what extent is Marxism a liberal ideology? My answer in this thread specifically discusses social liberalism

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad hi, thank you. I don't agree that social democracy equals social liberalism. Social democracy, in my understanding, is to get to socialism (the collectivisation of the means of production), not by a revolution, but by gradual reforms, that is, via playing the rules of democracy. Social liberalism is, IMK, a different thing, it is a hybrid economic system, with a partial redistribution of wealth based on the capitalist economy (taxes, etc. which are then redistributed, but the economy is free-market) (therefore the name "social liberalism", it is a mix of the two)

Ferdinand Lassalle, who was a friend and rival of Marx, indeed believed in democratic transformation towards socialism, and his ideas had resurgence in the late XIX-th century in the form of revisionism. But most modern socialist parties either abandoned Marxist view of socialism (like German SDP) or never adhered to it - e.g., French Socialists have their own tradition, which pre-dates Marx and developed independently from him (young Marx himself became interested in socialism and communism after spending a few years in Paris.)

The original pamphlet by Kautsky, which triggered Terrorism and Communism discussion, indeed reads as a modern exposition of social-democratic principles - but Kautsky strangely fails to cite the classics in his book, while the replies by Lenin and Trotsky do so extensively.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad "But most modern socialist parties either abandoned Marxist view of socialism (like German SDP) or never adhered to it" Agree, especially today, I would say that, factually, many French "Socialist Party" members (like Hollande, or Macron) are social liberals. From socialism, they turned into a hybrid socio-capitalist thing. Although I don't think there is a direct line with the original British social liberal theorists mentioned in my question, they just do this hybrid thing by pragmatism (I don't know actually)

FYI, Macron was never a socialist party member, even if he was in Holland's government. He is a genuine liberal in both European and American sense of the word (i.e., committed to liberal economy and liberal social values.)

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad Macron was a member of PS from 2006 to 2009. I contend he is not the best example I could found. Hollande, or Mitterrand are maybe better ones. He is not as liberal economically as he has the reputation of

I didn't know that he was a socialist - this pre-dates his stint in Hollandes government. He has evolved much during his presidency - there were too many objections to his economically liberal policies (or at least what was perceived as economically liberal in France) - this included massive strikes, nation-wide protests, etc.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad Yes. For socialists, he is a "libérale", but for "libéraux", he is a socialist. So his politics is called "en même temps" (both this and that)

It is hard to be more liberal than that in France. He touched some holy cows - like SNCF  and retirement - and paid dearly for this. By the time he run for the second mandate he was essentially broken.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Though most people don't realize it, the term 'socialism' predates Marx by a good bit. The early socialists were people who objected to the rampant egoistic individualism of industrial era capitalism, and wanted to establish that social groups and communities had rights and liberties equivalent the rights and liberties of individuals. In essence, these people would see industrial barons of the time move into communities, dig up the land for resources, pump smoke and waste into the air and water, dislocate people and disrupt social structures, all so that the industrialist could make profit for himself alone. The idea was that the individual's right to pursue profit had to be countered by a community's rights to maintain itself and thrive, hence social-ism.
Marx coopted 'socialism' to mean a state in which the capitalist class had been excised and the state itself controlled production in the people's name, but Marxism didn't absorb all of the old-style socialists, who had no problem with capitalism except for excessive selfish individualism. Those old-style socialists became 'social liberals' without really changing their programme: they wanted responsible, community-centered (or at least community-cognizant) capitalism that respected all individual's rights, not just the rights of the powerful and wealthy.
Socialism and social liberalism have similar ideals — a system of universals liberty and equality — but different approaches. The first wants to replace the capitalist system entirely while the second just wants to fix it. But they are often treated interchangeably by hard-line capitalists who see them all as losers who should shut up and go away. C'est la vie!

That largely depends on the context, country and era in which it is used.
Like you seem to think of these as fixed ideologies, but practically these are just adjectives. Liberal referring to "concerned with (individual) liberty" and social referring to "concerned with society, your fellow people". And unless you go to the most extreme positions of idk destructive egoism and swarm identities(?). Then these two are NOT mutually exclusive and lots of groups can adopt these labels, temporarily or permanently as part or expression of their ideology.
So in consequence lots of things can call themselves "social" if there is even the slightest hints that it does a benefit for society. Heck even capitalists believing in trickle down economics might argue for the social benefit of their policies. For example one of, if not the, most conservative party in the democratic spectrum in Germany is called CSU (Christian Social Union), where from the name alone you might have expected some workers movement with a particular Christian background.
Similarly "liberal" is often enough not employed in the sense of market deregulation, but in the sense of the lot less controversial "social liberalism". Like applying a laissez-faire attitude to how people spend their lives. So how people dress, what music they listen to, how they spend their free time, anything from equal rights, political expression, sexual plurality, recreational drug use and whatnot. That can cover the whole spectrum from individuality (being yourself) to individualism (rejecting the concept of societies and responsibility for other people and looking at the world solely from the perspective of the individual).
Now while lots of things can call themselves social and pair social with whatever other ideology they want to pursue. "Socialism" implies a much stronger focus on society. Which historically still covers a vast array of different ideologies, though their least common denominator is usually that they don't just seek redistribution and improvement of society, but also take aim at that the structural reasons for inequality within societies, chief among them the distribution of ownership of the means of production. So if you'd take a company, "social" could just be higher wages and better working conditions, while "socialism" demands workers be equal share and stakeholders in their company.
So the demand is not just economic benefits and hedonistic improvements, but political participation and self-determination, rather than a more comfortable life as second class citizens.
And theoretically that's supposed to be inherently democratic. If there are no longer classes and exploitation and if everyone is in the same class and has an equal membership and say in society, that's the logical conclusion.
Also when socialism first emerged "democracies" weren't really that plenty either and even minor political participation had to be fought for in bloody revolutions and those weren't always successful either. So the idea to achieve that by "democratic means" was kinda utopian given that you'd need a democracy in the first place and if you got one, also one with universal suffrage and not one that blatantly discriminates political power in favor of the wealthy (yes that happened). Otherwise all you'd ever got is a more social minded monarchy/aristocracy but no political participation of your own.
So combinations of socialism and democracy, could either be seen as superfluous as democracy should already be included or could be presented as bonus that is already included or could indicate a priority democracy first socialism later or socialism AND democracy and apparently since Lenin... "Socialism" (usually prefaced with "real" to indicate the discrepancy to the idea) first democracy later.
Now in modern terms "social democracy" usually refers to a more social minded form of democracy, whereas "democratic socialism" aims at getting socialism through democratic means or stress that it's socialism but democratic. But depending on the context any combination could have meant anything at different times and countries, again these are adjectives and people use and combine them how they think fits.
So unlike what one might expect, Lenin apparently wasn't even a member of the Socialist Revolution Party, but of the "Russian Social Democratic Labor Party" or rather the RSDLP(B) (="Bolshevics"). So not even socialist in name, but just social democracy.
Similarly while the German SPD has a long continuation in name, their ideology is a lot less consistent, from marxist socialist, to workers party, to just more social than the conservatives but trying to appeal to all people in society, they covered a lot of positions in the democratic spectrum and in the Weimar Republic and the DDR even split up or were forcefully merged with the communist party.
And likewise you have lots of "socialist" parties in various European nations that went the other way around and kept their name from their socialist origins but have long since then been social democrats rather than democratic socialists.
Also you could argue the other way around as to whether that kind of democracy already checks at least some boxes of socialism. As technically everything is owned by the state and private individuals have to fulfill requirements set by the majority. And that majority can also decide how much people get to keep as private income and how much is taken by the general public via taxes over which all people (at least in the theory of a democracy) can decide equally. Important positions of power are already under democratic control and not left to the tyranny of rich people, there is public broadcasting and at least the legal influence of rich people upon politics and the public opinion should be more limited than it used to be.
The thing is within the framework of a democracy theoretically reforms are possible that previously were only imaginable as revolutions. So technically this already is the "dictatorship" of the proletariat, as that group ought to be the majority in numbers and that's enough to construct a government of their peers by election.
Now the objection is most likely that of the private ownership of the means of production, that rich people can basically cash in and move collective assets as personal property, that wealth inequality an social disparity creates gradients of social, political and economic power which are still present even if they are no longer codified as they used to. That miss- and disinformation and populism prevent people from taking advantage of their political powers and so on. Also a government of their peers, is still a form of government and not really a democracy and especially when you think in terms of class, people in government usually have a different class than those that they end up governing, despite their origins.
But anyway: TL;DR that heavily depends on the specifics of who's using these terms.

Your answer is a precise and systematic analysis of the meanings of the terms. You insist a lot on the term "democracy" which isn't in my question. And also, my question concerns more history than really the semantics. Are the guys who developed "social liberalism" (so famously John Stuart Mill, etc.) historically connected to the guys who developed "socialism", that is the famous Marx, Babeuf, Engels, etc. etc.

@Starckman That depends on how narrow you define liberalism. If liberalism is just the idea of laissez-faire capitalism then they hardly match, if you consider that they all swam in the soup that is (post-)enlightenment "liberalism" with it's focus on liberating the individual then there are inevitable overlaps. Also "social democracy" is another term for the more social market economy covering many of these ideas of social liberalism, so might give that a read. Which has some connection to the other socialists, either seeing themselves as such, former team mates or enemies.
